# vim remove underline from line number

Tags: vim

I upgraded vim (macOS) using brew:

```
$ brew info vim
vim: stable 8.1.2100 (bottled), HEAD
```

After the upgrade, the line numbers at the right are underlined, for example, from the attached picture line number 1 appears like `1_____`, any idea how to remove the underline?

Happens only when having `:set relativenumber`

[image: vim underli]

Comment: What if you run `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: when enabling `:set relativenumber` the underline happens (also when running `vim -u NONE`)

Comment: Is the underline under every line number or only at the current line?

Comment: Is there anything else that is underlined which you didn't expect, if you have any syntax highlighted content in a buffer?

Comment: it is only the on every line number, the current line doesn't gets affected, this is an example when using `vim -u NONE` https://imgur.com/BSXPZy5

Comment: That's just the colorscheme. What is `:hi CursorLineNr`?

Comment: @Matt that was it `CursorLineNr   xxx term=bold cterm=underline ctermfg=12 gui=bold guifg=Yellow`, now need to find what is adding the `cterm=underline` since it is not defined in the colors schema

Comment: Try `:verbose hi CursorLineNr`

Comment: @Amadan poing to a line in my colors: `hi CursorLineNr    term=bold ctermfg=012 gui=bold` but I think this has been hardcoded: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/017ba07fa2cdc578245618717229444fd50c470d/src/highlight.c#L256

Comment: Seems like your colour scheme doesn't change `cterm`, so you're getting the default value of `cterm=underline`. Try to add `cterm=NONE`  (or whatever else you want: `:help highlight-cterm`) to your `hi CursorLineNr`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Latest versions defaults to underline: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/017ba07fa2cdc578245618717229444fd50c470d/src/highlight.c#L256

```
CursorLineNr term=bold cterm=underline ctermfg=Yellow gui=bold guifg=Yellow
```

My templates was using only:

```
hi CursorLineNr    term=bold ctermfg=012 gui=bold
```

The fix was to define `cterm`:

```
hi CursorLineNr    term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=012 gui=bold
```

Comment: My web site service provider's machine uses vim 8.2 and I have to set `LineNr`, not `CursorLineNr`. The `hi` command showed me which ones were set to `underline` and I experimented until I got the result I wanted.

Comment: what an awful choice

Comment: I where is `cterm` defined?

Comment: is this done in vim?

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix for this in the .minttyrc as this was driving me crazy as well.

There is a setting in there for `Term=vt100`
Edit the .minttyrc in your home dir and comment out or remove the line 
`Term=vt100`. 
Save the file and close the CLI and reopen a new one. The underline should now be gone from vi from then on. I hope this helps.